# Connect to AWS DocumentDB from Docker Kafka Connect Container with SSL

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, aws-documentdb

I am trying to connect to my AWS Document DB from a local Kafka Connect Docker container using SSL. I've followed [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html) and created the rds-trustore.jks file from .pem file which is provided by AWS itself. Then I've set the environment variables stated [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/connect/index.html#connectconfigs_ssl.truststore.location) as below.

> CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/path/to/my/rds-trustore.jks
> CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=<password>

The problem is, when I try to register a debezium mongodb source connector with the following configuration

> "mongodb.ssl.enabled": "true"

I get the error

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1426)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1336)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:841)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1211)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:539)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 30 more
```

Anybody has any ideas?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the keystore to JVM as described in the AWS documentation

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore: <truststore>
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword: <truststorePassword>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you know where can I add these values? I am using the [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base) provided by Confluent

Comment: Generally via -D on the command line, in your scenario it depends who is actually trying to connect to the database. Is it MongoDB who tries to connect to AWS?